# What is the Potterverse?

Tags: harry-potter, fans

I really want to know what the Potterverse is. Is it just another synonym for the Harry Potter fandom?

Answer (score 22):

The [Potterverse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Potterverse) is:

> The fictional universe which is the setting of the Harry Potter series.

It's a fandom slang word for the *world* of Harry Potter.

---

Generally speaking, *[person]*-verse is often used as a fandom slang word for the fictional world or universe associated with the person. For example:

- the Whoniverse is the universe of Doctor Who
- the Buffyverse is the world of Buffy the Vampire Slayer and Angel
- the Whedonverse covers the world(s) of Joss Whedon shows and movies, including the Buffyverse, Firefly/Serenity, and Dollhouse.

Comment: For the record, the earliest reference I could find was Feb 2000; http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/features/essays/issue15/hbs/ although I'm sure the term dramatically pre-dates that on the various potter forums.